# How can I set a Django model property to always be returned?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a User model which inherits from the Abstract User Model from `django.contrib.auth`. For minimal example this could be it:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
     middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        full = ''
        if self.title:
            full += self.title + ' '
        if self.first_name:
            full += self.first_name + ' '
        if self.middle_name:
            full += self.middle_name + ' '
        if self.last_name:
            full += self.last_name + ' '
        return full.strip()
```

When creating a user serialiser with the ModelSerializer like this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

the full_name property doesn't show up. I could solve this by explicitly adding the field via a `SerializerMethodField` but as we have a a lot of different serialisers for the user and abstract models above, I would like to always have it returned as if it was a field. Do I need to add a field to the model? Or is there a way I didn't see yet?

Comment: Try to add `full_name = serializers.CharField()` to your `UserSerializer` definition and change `Meta.fields` to `fields = ["middle_name", "title", "full_name"]`. Take a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer, it can inspect and generated fields in serializers based on model's fields. I guess there is no way to predict what type the property like `full_name` returns.

Comment: But this isn't what I wanted right? I want the serializer to treat the field as if it was a model field without explicitly including it into the fields. Actually I added -> str to specify the type the property returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.myproperty
```

This is the function you have to add to your model.

Comment: Wouldn't this just return the property when I call the instance? This isn't what I am looking for as I would like the "myproperty" to act as a field on the model.

Comment: I think fields would do it but you have to explicitly call these fields and not use __all__